# How to recognise date format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application I am working on a module of converting string to MMMM yyyy date format and insert it in database

**Input**:-  NSString which may be of **MMMM yyyy** or **dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss** format
**Output**:- NSString with **MMMM yyyy** format

And I Implement method like below

```
-(NSString *)convertToRequiredDataString:(NSString *)downloadedString
{
    NSString *stringToInsert=downloadedString;
    NSArray *checkArray=[stringToInsert componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    if (checkArray.count>=2) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy 00:00:00"];
        NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:stringToInsert];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
        stringToInsert=[formatter stringFromDate:date];
        if (!stringToInsert) {
            stringToInsert=@"";
        }
    }
    return stringToInsert;
}
```

My question is that, Instead of checking the array length as checkArray.count>=2  is there any logically correct way of implementation possible

Comment: Are these columns in the database of type TIMESTAMP or TEXT?

Comment: they are of type TEXT

Comment: well that's a mistake; it means you cannot do any queries based on this date/time.

Comment: Write a validation method using a `NSDateFormatter` to create dates for both formats. `dateFromString:` returns `nil` on failure.

Comment: That looks like a nice trick thanks